# Manipulate Symfony 2 UploadFile object in a unit test

Tags: php, file, unit-testing, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony2 project.
I created a simple `TempFile` class to manipulate an UploadFile. Here is my constructor :

```
public function __construct(UploadedFile $file, $destination, $suffix)
{
    $this->file             = $file;
    $this->destination      = $destination;
    $this->fileId           = sprintf('%s_%s', uniqid(), (string) $suffix);
}
```

And my `move` method

```
public function move()
{
    $extension = $this->file->guessExtension();
    if (!$extension) {
        throw new \Exception(__METHOD__ . ' -> Unable to detect extension');
    }

    $this->tmpFileName = sprintf('%s.%s', $this->fileId, $extension);
    $this->file->move($this->destination, $this->tmpFileName);
}
```

I try to create an `UploadFile` object in my test and here is what I did :

```
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'upload');
    imagepng(imagecreatetruecolor(10, 10), $this->file);
    $this->uploadedFile = new UploadedFile($this->file, "test.png");
}

public function testMoveWithAValidUploadedFile()
{
    $tempFile = new TempFile($this->uploadedFile, '/tmp', 'tmp');
    $tempFile->move();
    // Future assertion
}
```

I have the following error :

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException: The file "test.png" was not uploaded due to an unknown error
```

Any ideas ?

Thx,
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From memory, Symfony2 checks if a file was uploaded as part of the request using `is_uploaded_file()`. This can be overridden using the test mode of the `UploadedFile` class. You can also define which PHP upload error code constitutes success.

```
copy(__DIR__ . '/Fixtures/test.pdf', '/tmp/test.pdf');
new UploadedFile(
    '/tmp/test.pdf',
    'original.pdf',
    null,
    null,
    UPLOAD_ERR_OK,
    true /* test */
)
```